# Why doesn't looping over seq output work if I change IFS?

Tags: bash

```
$ end=7
$ for i in $(seq 1 $end); do echo $((i*i)); done
1  
4  
9  
16  
25  
36  
49
```

```
$ IFS="" # or anything
# this gives same error : for i in $(seq 1 $end); do let b=i*i; echo $b; done
$ for i in $(seq 1 $end); do echo $((i*i)); done
-bash: 1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7: syntax error in expression (error token is "2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7")
```

```
$ unset IFS
$ for i in $(seq 1 $end); do echo $((i*i)); done
1  
4  
9  
16  
25  
36  
49
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be when you change `IFS`?

Comment: Where's the bug?

Comment: BTW, `seq` is bad practice in the first place, in part _because_ word-splitting (as controlled by IFS) is needed to interpret its output. The shell has built-in arithmetic features, and you should use them.

Comment: `for ((i=1; i<=end; i++)); do echo "$((i*i))"; done` doesn't require word-splitting anywhere, so IFS won't change how it behaves. Beyond that, I don't see a specific question here enough to be able to answer. (Yes, interpreting `seq`'s output involves IFS, but the question isn't clear enough for me to have any confidence that that statement in fact answers it).

Comment: ...btw, if you describe, in English, what your interpretation _is_, that would help us understand better whether you are in fact "misinterpreting something". Showing us several examples of bash's output doesn't tell us why you think that output is wrong or what you think it _should_ be instead.

Comment: (also, running an external command like `seq` has a performance penalty; no reason to pay to execute a separate binary for something the shell can do itself).

Answer (score 4):

`IFS` is what splits `seq`'s output into words. If it's not split into words, it's *one* word, with a bunch of newlines inside it.

So, let's say you ran:

```
let b = '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10' * '1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10'
```

It's obvious why that's wrong, right?

But when you don't have `IFS` configured to split `seq`'s output into separate words, that's what you're doing.